# Unable to make HttpClient request

Tags: java, httpclient

I am using `HTTPClient` to make a web request. From the linux part, using the following command returns the status as `OK`. The same thing from the java is returning  unauthorized status code `401`.

Command from linux:

```
curl -X GET -ik -H 'Accept: application/json' --user test:test http://api.uat.testapi.com
```

To access this, I am using java code as below:

```
 HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("http://api.uat.testapi.com/");                 
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();         
            httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials( new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost.getPort()), 
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("test","test"));
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://api.uat.testapi.com/");
            httppost.addHeader("Accept","application/json");            
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
            System.out.println("status>>>>"+response.getStatusLine());
```

I am getting the response as: `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`.

Any pointers to solve this will be helpful

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in the command you seem to use `GET` while in the Java code you use `POST` - from my POV you are comparing two rather different things...

Comment: Same thing happening with the method `GET`.

Comment: the host which i am trying to access in original is protected with the username/password, So, using setCredentials of httpClient is not binding the credentials to the requestURI. i Think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set HttpState to use authentication. Use

```
httpClient.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
```

to do the same.

Comment: Hi, I am using http 4.1 apache client, i didn't find the mehtod setAuthenticationPReemptive(true), there? please tell me how to set that.

Comment: Ok.. for Http 4.1 you can use...
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
localContext.setAttribute("http.auth.scheme-pref", Arrays.asList(new String[] {"basic"}));

I think this will work.:-)

Comment: Hi Abhutra, I am really new to this, i have pasted the code as is, after setting the credentials, still getting the same response. Any other changes do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're making a GET request with curl and a POST request with HttpClient; I suspect POST requests are not being accepted by the server.

Do you need to use HttpGet instead:

```
HttpGet method = new HttpGet("http://api.uat.testapi.com");
...
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(method);
```

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
try below code :

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("url").openConnection();

connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+
            new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode( "username:password".getBytes() ));

System.out.println("status>>>>"+connection.getResponseCode());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use follwing code....make changes according to ur setup ex url etc

```
 DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("YOURURL");

        System.out.println("executing request" + httpget.getRequestLine());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        if (entity != null) {
            System.out.println("Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
    }
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
 finally {
        // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
        // shut down the connection manager to ensure
        // immediate deallocation of all system resources
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
```